# Using template values in Symfony2 bundle configuration

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, configuration, bundle

In short, I'm trying to achieve the following config file structure:

```
acmebundle:
  connections:
    @template:
      param1: value1
      param2: value2
    conn1:
      extends: @template
      param2: value3
```

During the normalization process, I want any connection, whose name starts with "@" (in this case @template) to be discarded and not validated at all. But before that, all other connections that extend it, should have all the @template values populated within them, before the validation process.

**Is that possible at all? Any hints would be appreciated.**

At the moment I have this:

```
acmebundle:
  connections:
    @template: &template
      abstract: true
      param1: value1
      param2: value2
    conn1:
      <<: *template
      abstract: false
      param2: value3
```

And I parse it like this:

```
private function getConnectionsNode()
{
    $builder = new TreeBuilder();
    $node = $builder->root('connections');

    $node
        ->isRequired()
        ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
        ->useAttributeAsKey('id')
        ->prototype('array')
        ->beforeNormalization()
            ->ifTrue(function($v) {
                return isset($v['abstract']) && true === $v['abstract'];
            })
            ->then(function($v) {
                // Set dummy params to ensure validation is passed
                if (empty($v['param1'])) {
                    $v['param1'] = 'undefined';
                }
                if (empty($v['param2'])) {
                    $v['param2'] = 'undefined';
                }
                return $v;
            })
        ->end()
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('abstract')
                    ->defaultFalse()
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('param1')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                ->scalarNode('param2')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $node;
}
```

It works, but it's ugly, as I have to specify abstract:false on every real connection and I have to rely on YML-specific feature for copy-paste of the template values.